# sublime differentiate between single line comments and multiline comments

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I use sublime text 2 for PHP and now also for Python. There I can distinguish between single line and multi line comments.
For instanse, if you type:

```
/* [enter]
```

sublime autocompletes to:

```
/*
[cursor is here]
*/
```

this doesn't work for the php equivalent for single line comments:

```
// some comment [enter]
```

resutls in:

```
// some comment
[cursor is here]
```

I like to have this behaviour in Python as well.
In python however, if I use "#" for a single line comment I get this:

```
# some comment [enter]
```

results in:

```
# some comment
# [cursor is here]
```

This is annoyting since I have to backspace twice to undo it. The multiline comment with triple quotes doesn't work at all. (it highlights correctly, but does not autocomplete)

How can I change this? Is there some keybinding I can change or is it a syntax specific thing?

EDIT:
installed packages:
- package control
- DocBlockR
- SideBarEnhancements
- SublimeLinter
- Synchronized Scrolling

Comment: what plugins do you have installed? I don't see this behavior with ST3 on Windows. Are you using DocBlockr?

Comment: yes, I added the list of packages to the post. I use ST2 on windows 8.1 64x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think I've figured this out - it doesn't have anything to do with DocBlockr. First, open `Packages/Python/Miscellaneous.tmPreferences` (where `Packages` is the folder opened when going to `Preferences -> Browse Packages...`) and delete the following lines (they should be lines 19-24):

```xml
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>TM_COMMENT_START</string>
    <key>value</key>
    <string># </string>
</dict>
```

Save that file. Next, create a new file (with XML syntax, if you want highlighting) with the following contents:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Comments</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>source.python</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>shellVariables</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>TM_COMMENT_START</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string># </string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>uuid</key>
    <string>A67A8BD9-A951-406A-9175-018DD4B52FD1</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Save this file as `Packages/Python/Comments.tmPreferences`. Restart Sublime, and you should be all set.